# Why does -4 <= -4 evaluate true and why does 9>=9 evaluate true in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

was working on some practice exercise in Ruby on codeacademy and came across these two questions. Not sure if I clearly understand why does -4 <= -4 evaluate true and why does 9>=9 evaluate true in Ruby? Could someone please explain so I can have a better understanding? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`<=` the is less-than-or-equal-to operator

To answer the question whether `a <= b` for numbers `a` and `b` you can ask yourself two questions:

1. is `a` less than `b`?
2. is `a` equal to `b`?

If either question results in "Yes", then the `<=` operator will evaluate to `true`.

For your example

- `-4 <= -4`

  1. is `-4` less than `-4`? "No"
  2. is `-4` equal to `-4`? "Yes"

Since the answer to the second question is "Yes", `-4 <= -4` is `true`

Comment: I know its a silly question but thank you so much for explaining it! Makes so much sense to me now.

Comment: Your welcome; it is good to have solid math background for logic in programming.

Answer (score 1):

`-4 <= -4` means -4 is less than **or equal to** -4. Since -4 is the same as -4, it evaluates to true.

The same is true with `9 >= 9`. 9 is equal to 9, and thus the expression evaluates to true.

Answer (score 1):

Because `<=` means "less than *or* equal to", and `>=` means "greater than *or* equal to", and all numbers are equal to themselves.

Answer (score 0):

`<=` means "less than to equal to". -4 is equal to -4, so it's also "less than **or equal to**" -4.

Similarly, `>=` means "greater than or equal to". 9 is equal to 9, so it's also "greater than **or equal to**" 9.